# How to make effect in the docker image when files are locally edited?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I run my development project as docker image. I test like;

```
#docker-compose up
```

I edited one file locally. but when i again run #docker-compose up, I do not see my changes. What command I need to run?

**My docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    image: lobdocker/eps-portal:latest
    volumes:
       - /var/www/storage
    env_file: '.env'
    working_dir: /app
    ports:
       - 8089:80
```

Comment: "Edited one file locally" - do you mean that you edited inside the docker container or in docker-compose.yaml file or in Dockerfile?

Comment: @ShobanSundar no .edited my source code(java/php file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker compose will always look for the image when you specify it like that.

Use the build property to point to a local folder, which you can build before upping.

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build: mydir/
    image: lobdocker/eps-portal:latest
    volumes:
       - /var/www/storage
    env_file: '.env'
    working_dir: /app
    ports:
       - 8089:80
```

Comment: I'm getting following error//ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 5, column 10// my docker-compose.yml file is inside my projectfolder (epsportal). SO i gave path as build: epsportal/ . But it gives issue

Comment: should probably have been just . (dot) then, if they reside in the same directory. Try experimenting with this a bit, i.e. from examples on the net, and see if you cannot manage it.

Answer (score 0):

before docker-compose up, you have to build the docker image once again. So that the changes will reflect. it wont take much time though you already builds the image. So the comments are

$ docker-compose build

then

$ docker-compose up

Note: **docker-compose up -d** will run in background

Comment: But I haven't committed the code. Locally I edited my files. and I want to test that in the docked environment

Comment: # docker-compose build  gives //
app uses an image, skipping//

Comment: I have edited my question with docker-compose.yml file

Answer (score 0):

If you want your changes to be reflected you need to `commit` the image first,
here is the command 
`docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]` 
To commit the changes from the dockerfile you have to use `--change` option, you can get more information [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/)

To change the code locally inside a container you can use `docker exec` command, to get the console access and whatever changes you make will be their until the container is destroyed.